# Django TemplateDoesNotExist, but traceback reaches views.py

Tags: python, django

I have a begin.html file that I'm trying to access at localhost:8000/begin, but I get the DjangoTemplateDoesNotExist error when trying to access it.

The only thing in that template is

```
<h1>welcome to my app !</h1>
```

and it's in the app/template directory.

In the same app directory is my views.py file, which contains

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def begin(request):
    print("DEBUG STATEMENT")
    return render(request, "template/begin.html", {})
```

The return statement in begin is reached, as both the print statement and the traceback tell me, but Django can't find the template after.

If it's relevant, my urls.py file is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from app.views import begin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^begin/$', begin, name = 'begin')
]
```

in the project directory.

Comment: Try to remove 'templates' from the render method. Use just 'begin.html'.

Comment: what does you folder structure look like in your app?

Comment: That gave me the same error.

Comment: if you follow the django suggested structure is should be `templates/app_name/begin.html` and your string in render should be `"app_name/begin.html"`

Comment: @KeiferSebastian I have my app directory, my project directory, my manage.py, and a db.sqlite3 in my highest level directory. The app has two subdirectories - template and migrations.

Comment: @plzhalpplzxubtunu has happened to me before.

Comment: Please do mind your language though.

Comment: can you post the template configuration in your `settings.py` file please?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided the information, i take it as you mean `urls.py` inside your app. If you have two `urls.py` you need to redirect from the first urls where django looks to the other one.

```
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^', include('YOURAPPNAME.urls'))
]
```

In your appdirectory in urls.py write

```
from . import views //importing views from current directory
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^begin/$' views.begin, name=begin)
]
```

Another tip, consider using render_to_response when you are using a http response, i know render is newer but since you're using a response i would go with render_to_response in your case, and skip the context.

```
return render_to_response('YOURAPPNAME'/begin.html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your template structure like this,

```
your_app_name
--> **templates**
    --> **your_app_name**
        --> **'begin.html'**
--> static
--> models.py
--> ........
```

Then, change your views, like this,

```
return render(request, "your_app_name/begin.html", {})
```

Django as default check for the directory under the name "templates", in your app_directory.
When accommodating multiple apps, for easiness ​templates are kept under the directory with app_name.

From the [docs](https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/&grqid=0AJtHAA1&hl=en-IN),

> It’s possible – and preferable – to organize templates in subdirectories inside each directory containing templates. The convention is to make a subdirectory for each Django app, with subdirectories within those subdirectories as needed.
>
> Do this for your own sanity. Storing all templates in the root level of a single directory gets messy.
>
> When APP_DIRS is True, DjangoTemplates engines look for templates in the **templates** subdirectory of installed applications. This generic name was kept for backwards-compatibility.